# Symfony 2 & Doctrine 2 ORM transactions. Close EntityManager?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

This is a simple question. In the [Doctrine 2 ORM 2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#exception-handling) you can read:

> When using explicit transaction demarcation and an exception occurs,
>   the transaction should be rolled back immediately and the
>   `EntityManager` closed by invoking `EntityManager#close()` and
>   subsequently discarded, as demonstrated in the example above.

I understand that I should close the `EntityManager`, but the example given a few lines above

```
<?php
// $em instanceof EntityManager
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit
try {
    //... do some work
    $user = new User;
    $user->setName('George');
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

I can't see `$em->close();` inside the catch block.

So, should I or shouldn't I close the EntityManager with `$em->close();`?

Comment: Yes, you should use close.  Not sure why the example does not show it.  Consider opening a documentation issue.  The manager is not automatically closed in this case because, if it was, then the rollback would not work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use close then